Left moka pot on stove and burnt it
I left my Moka pot on the stove for a long time so the handle and the top knob got burnt, melted and came off. The inside is burnt. any way to fix it? Or do I need to get a new one?

Welcome to coffee.SE! Could you maybe share some photos of the damage? That might help others see what exactly is broken and to what extent.

IMO you should replace it. Not a great expense and you should have a peace of mind regarding safety features of a moka pot (valve) not to mention that whenever you make a flawed cup of coffee you would not know what's the exact cause.

The metal part is usually not the issue - residues etc. can typically be cleaned off, discoloration is mostly cosmetic.
However, if the handle and knob are gone, I would very much recommend replacing the device. This is for me a safety issue: a Mokka is used typically on a stove and during use you need to be able to handle it as needed. This includes opening/closing the lid and moving it off the heat at some point. You could try this with a potholder or something, but especially if something goes not ideal (e.g. accidentally setting the stove too high or being distracted for a bit) you want to be able to just grab the Mokka safely and quickly.
Please do yourself a favor and get a new Mokka.
